# Proving 2+4+6+...+2n = n(n+1) without induction

Tags: summation, proof-writing, induction

This is the
[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRjsf.jpg)

I have managed to find the formula for part a) which is n(n+1) for all natural numbers n, but I'm not sure how to prove it directly. Can I just say that the summation of 2i is the same as the sums of the summation of i plus the summation of i as the proof?

I have managed to do part b) which uses induction to prove that the summation of even numbers can be found using the formula n(n+1).

Comment: Yes, that works. We have$$\sum_{i=1}^n (i + i) = \sum_{i=1}^n i + \sum_{i=1}^n i,$$which is really$$(1 + 1) + (2 + 2) + \ldots + (n + n) = (1 + 2+ \ldots + n) + (1 + 2+ \ldots + n),$$because we are free to rearrange summation as we choose. That is, addition is *commutative* (and associative).

Comment: You may be interested in "Proof without words" for "sum of first n positive integers" using a web search.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
2+4+\dots+2n =2(1+2+\dots+n) =2\left (\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)=n(n+1)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint for even $n$:
$$\left.\begin{align}
&2+2n&=2(n+1)\\
&4+(2n-2)&=2(n+1)\\
&6+(2n-4)&=2(n+1)\\
&\dots\\
&n+(n+2)&=2(n+1)
\end{align}\right \}\frac n2\text{ rows }$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align} 2 + 4 + \dots + 2n &= (1 + \dots + n) + (1 + \dots + n) \cr & = (1 + 2 + \dots + n) + (n + (n-1) + \dots + 1) \cr & = (n+1) + \dots + (n+1) = n(n+1)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should be enough. You can also say:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}2i = 2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}i = 2 \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to prove that
$$
1+2+\dotsb+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \binom{n+1}{2}
$$
The RHS counts the $2$ element subsets of $A=\{0,1,\dotsc, n\}$. We note that there are $i$ subsets of $A$ whose max element is $i$ for $0\leq i\leq n$. The LHS counts the $2$ element subsets of $A$ in this way.